# Can I publish my profile picture for all users of Mac Mail?

Tags: mail.app

When you open an email from someone in Mac Mail, their profile picture (set in the Contacts app) is displayed. If a profile pic is not found, a circle with that user's initials is displayed.

Is there a way to publish a profile pic associated with my email address, so any user of Mac Mail can see that profile pic when I send them emails?

For Gmail web clients, I need to set a profile pic in Google+. For the Fastmail web client, I need to set a profile pic on Gravatar. But I don't know of a way for Mac Mail. Is there one?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this.

The Mail app on the desktop [only retrieves profile pictures from the local machine](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19176?locale=en_GB), that is, from the Contacts app, from your user account, and from `~/Library/Images/People/`.